# 房地产 和 不动产有什么区别？Moreover i want to know the correct pronunciation of 不 of 不动产

Tags: difference, pronunciation

I've searched for the differences between 房地产 and 不动产 but the results are all written in Chinese and my Chinese level is not enough to read them.

I guess that 不动产 is more related to business purpose and 房地产 is rather for real life purpose(buying, selling, borrowing a house or an apartment etc)

I need the explanation which is written in English for now.

BTW can I pronounce 不 of 不动产 with 2nd tone? I wonder if there exists some exception of the tone change rule of 不 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

房(house)地(land)产 (estate)  --> building and land property = real estate

不动(fixed location)产(estate)  --> property that is fixed to a  location, including building and land property = real estate

- 房地产 is the narrower definition of real estate (ownership of a building, a house, or a piece of land)
- 不动产 is the broader definition of real estate (It refers to an object that occupies a fixed position in space according to natural properties or legal regulations and its economic value will be affected after movement. It included but was not limited to ownership of houses and land)

Real estate (property) that is not house or land:

detached garages, patios, swimming pools, or other permanent structures. Crops and other natural resources that are attached to a piece of land are also considered real property. For example, a mine

In short, if you want to buy a house or a piece of land, you can talk to a 房地产 or 不动产 agency, but you need to deal with a 不动产 agency if you want to acquire a gold mine

Answer (score 2):

For the pronunciation problem: yes, the standard pronunciation is to use the 2nd tone for 不. There is no exception here. 不 becomes the 2nd tone when the next character is 4th tone, and 动 is 4th tone.

Answer (score 0):

不动产 is Japanese, not Chinese. 房地产 is Chinese.

To me, 不动产 is more or less a direct (and not so good) translation of the English term "illiquid assets." Therefore it does not refer to real estate / property directly.

OTOH, 房地产 is not a translation and refers to real estate / property directly.

Comment: Many Japanese terms are widely used by the Chinese nowadays, for example, 空港  is a Japanese term, yet most Chinese know this word as "Airport"

Comment: Agreed, though most of terms are rarely used. Say, 航母 is used over 空母, and 機場 is used over 空港.